# Find the number of integers 1≤x≤210 which are divided by two of the numbers 3,5,7

Tags: divisibility, integers

I went with;

Numbers that can be divided by **$3,5$** can also be divided with **$15$**. These are $15,30,45,60,75,90,105,120,135,150,165,180,195,210$

Numbers that can be divided by **$3,7$** can also be divided with **$21$**. These are $21,42,63,84,105,126,147,168,189$

Numbers that can be divided by **$5,7$** can also be divided with **$35$**. These are 
$35,70,105,140,175,210$

So total number of integers are $14+9+6=$**$29$**

But I'm not sure about my answer.

Comment: Have you checked you aren't counting an integer twice?

Comment: Yes, I saw it after you mention it. I've counted 105 and 210 multiple times. The answer is 26.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$210= 3 \times 5 \times 7 \times 2$$

$$\frac{210}{3 \times 5} = 2 \times 7$$

$$\frac{210}{3 \times 7} = 2 \times 5$$

$$\frac{210}{5 \times 7} = 3 \times 2$$

If a number is divisible by all $3$ numbers, it will appear in each list, hence we need to substract $2 \times$ number of multiples of $3 \times 5 \times 7$.

Hence the desired number is

$$2 \times 7+ 2 \times 5 + 3 \times 2 - 2 \times \frac{210}{3 \times 5 \times 7}=2(7+5+3-2)=26$$

Comment: you are welcome. Note that while listing multiples of $21$, $169=13^2$ is not a multiple of $21$, it should be $168$.

Comment: Yes, it's not:) My mistake. I edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not 29 you count 210 twice and 105 three times , so the number of natural number which are devided two of the number 3 5 7 is 26 .

Comment: Yes, this is the answer. I've counted them multiple times. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome .